# Why does the 'complete' parameter fire before the action parameter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assumed that the fade action would fire first, once completed the 'complete' action would fire after; but it seems in this case the alert fires first and then the after I close the alert, the fade executes.

HTML

```
<ol>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
</ol>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ol").fadeOut('slow',alert('ninja'))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The completion argument needs to be a function. You're calling the function immediately, not passing a function:

```
$("ol").fadeOut('slow', function() { alert('ninja'); });
```